# setup an aspnet developer solution

Tags: asp.net, git, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

I'm testing the newest StarterWeb ( [aspnet vnext template](https://github.com/aspnet/Templates) ) but having trouble compiling it. I setup through vs2015 Tools/Nuget package manager/Settings -> Package Sources this only feed for aspnetcidev. I expect to keep in sync with latest development packages, but at the dnu restore I got an unresolved dependency message:

```
 CACHE https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/flatcontainer/system.linq.expressions/index.json
 Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect >= 2.0.0-rc1-210191231
 Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native >= 1.2.0-rc
```

Also, the [myget gallery](http://myget.org/gallery/aspnetcidev) for aspnetcidev the OpenIdConnect package is still at v1.0.0-rc2-15942.

What is the right way to compile such dev solution? More generally, is there a best practice to establish a solution where I can setup dependencies directly on local git sources of aspnet and corefx to be able to enter debug mode in these sources?

Comment: partly solved adding follow feed that I found browsing the build code of Templates ( https://www.myget.org/F/azureadwebstacknightly ) that solved for the OpenIdConnect package but still the DiaSymReader unresolved. I wondering which best practice to locate correct feed in these cases for example I tried to search web for that "Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native >= 1.2.0-rc" and the response was at nuget where current 1.3.3 exists and 1.2.0-rc too but is strange that adding that feed ( https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ ) it still fails to solve the dependancy.

Comment: solved with follow feeds config:
<add key="aspnetvnext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/" />
<add key="azureadwebstacknightly" value="https://www.myget.org/F/azureadwebstacknightly/api/v3/index.json" />
and adding unmeet dependency of "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-rc2-15951", to the project.json using the quick actions helper from visual studio.

Comment: Definitively follow packages sources resolve: https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/, https://www.myget.org/F/azureadwebstacknightly/api/v3/flatcontainer/, https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetcidev/api/v3/flatcontainer/, https://nuget.org/api/v2/. I noticed that fact after clearing out the %HOME%/.dnx/packages folder and forcing a new download of packages, infact adding and removing feeds from my nuget.config filled my local packages folder with the needed packages and previous config with only 2 feeds is not enough cause was based on my particular local cached packages.